# How to use "seems to be"

Tags: word-usage

What is the correct way to say this..

> - I just checked my bank account and that **seems to be have been** activated.
> - I just checked my bank account and that **seems** activated.
> - I just checked my bank account and that **seems to be** activated.

Comment: You will want to use the pronoun **it** when referring back to your bank account.  Your sentence should be, *I just checked my bank account and **it**...*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you're trying to say, *it* may be more appropriate than *that*.

The first example has a *be* as well as *have been*, which isn't appropriate. It is using *activate* as a verb, in the passive voice, and is fine as:

> I just checked my bank account and that seems to have been activated.

The other two examples are both fine, and they use *activated* as an adjective. Both *to seem* and *to be* are **linking verbs**, so they can take adjectives as (subject) complements, taking the place of a normal noun object. In the second example, *seem* is a linking verb, and in the third, *seem* is a catenative verb taking a *to*-infinitive as complement, and *be* is a linking verb.

As to *it* versus *that*, *that* is mostly appropriate if its antecedent is in another sentence, while *it* works if the antecedent is *my bank account*, or if the antecedent is in another sentence.

Answer (score 0):

To me, *seem* actually has a different meaning when used as a linking verb and a concatenative verb.

As a concatenative verb (eg *seems to have been*), it is evaluation of an objective state of affairs. *My bank account seems to have been activated* means "as far as I can tell, my bank account has been activated".

As a linking verb (eg *seems activated*) it is a subjective evalution: "it gives me the impression of ... ". This is not really consistent with the objective question of whether a bank account is working or not, so for me "My bank account seems activated" appears unnatural. I might say that my friend seemed activated, if something has happened to excite him.

As for *It seems to be activated* vs *It seems to have been activated* - the first is taking *activated* as an adjective, which is less common (except in the phrase *activated charcoal*). The second it is the past participle of *activate*, so that is a passive clause, and seems to me to fit better.

As others have said, *it* is much better than *that* in those examples (though there are some dialects - eg, Norfolk - that use *that* in that way.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can say the following:

> I just checked my bank account and that seems to  have been activated.
>
> I just checked my bank account and that seems activated.
>
> I just checked my bank account and that seems to be activated.

Comment: It would sound better if you used "it" instead of "that" in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

The first two options are grammatically incorrect.

The third option is correct and can be used, but 'that' should be replaced with 'it'.
i.e. I just checked my bank account and it seems to be activated.

However, a better option would be :
I just checked my bank account and it seems to have been activated.